# How to Boot GParted on UEFI Hyper-V VM?

Tags: linux, centos, gparted, hyper-v

I need to expand the / partition on a Linux CentOS 7.3 Hyper-V Gen 2 virtual machine.  (secure boot is disabled)

From what I've read, the procedure is: 1) expand the vhdx using Hyper-V Manager, and 2) boot into GParted and extend the partition to use the free space.

The problem is I can't boot from the GParted ISO. I've moved the DVD drive to the top of the list in the Hyper-V Firmware Boot order, and the boot process starts... I select "Boot to RAM" from the GParted menu, then it hangs. The last message received in the console is:

```
   * copying /live/medium/live/filesystem.squashfs to RAM
   sending incremental file list
   filesystem.squashfs
```

Also tried 'Default' and 'Failsafe' modes from the GParted menu - stil hangs.

Can I edit the `shim.efi` file appearing in the Hyper-V Firmware Boot order?

Should I create a UEFI-bootable image of GParted on a USB Drive as described [here](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php)?

Comment: did you successfully extend the vhdx?

Comment: Yes, I've expanded the vhdx by 20GB. Of course CentOS can't see it.  I might try another partition tool.  But I think my own ignorance of Hyper-V's implementation of UEFI is the problem.

Comment: check in the CentOS Terminal, if the size of your partition. Should be `fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Does this return the new (+20GB) or the old storage size?

Comment: `PS H:\VirtualMachines\CentOS> ls .\CentOS.vhdx | select @{Name='Size GB';Expression={$_.Length/1GB}}

    Size GB
    -------
50.00390625

# df -h /dev/sda2
Filesystem 

Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2  31G  26G  3.8G   88% /`

Comment: short answer: no, the OS can't see the space. it's an ext4 file system. I cant umount / so I don't know of any way to extend the partition without a partion tool like GParted.

Comment: The space is allocated for the vhdx. So it is availabe in the guest machine. Can you log into the Centos? if so run there the fdisk command I mentioned above.  The space should be there as unused space and now you need to extend the ext4

Comment: Thanks for the help Joe. I may want to repost the question. Currently I'm asking how to boot GParted on a UEFI/GPT Hyper-V virtual machine. A better question might be "how to resize a mounted Linux partition" (in my case the / partition). As far as I know, this is **not possible**. As for the output of `fdisk -l`, the OS does report /dev/sda at 53 GB. So the additional space is in fact seen by the OS. But the output of `parted print` and 'lsblk` show my partitions: /boot/efi (sda1), / (sda2), and swap (sda3) at the same sizes they were before expansion of the vhdx in Hyper-V Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and noticed that a `Generation 2` `Hyper-v` VM would not boot the `gparted v 1.5.0.1-amd64` iso with a basic configuration.

I was able to boot the `gparted` iso by going to `firmware` -> `boot order` and moving DVD to the top of the list ahead of the efi entry.

Note: After you are done, you should move the DVD entry in firmware to below the efi and main boot device as it does appear to slow the boot time quite a lot even without a DVD attached.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand filesystem size on live OS without unmount / rebooting.

> ```
> dnf install -y cloud-utils-growpart  # install growpart utility
> growpart /dev/sda 1     # grows the partition; note the space
> resize2fs /dev/sda1     # grows the filesystem
> ```

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/937351)